# $compile containing function as attribute value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I'm facing one issue with $compile.
The code I've written is very big hence I'm create one small example to replicate this issue.
Suppose I've a button in my page.
When user clicks on that button, one more button will be created which will be having ng-click method as shown below:

```
$scope.showAlert = function(){
       alert('pass'); 
    }
    $scope.createExample = function() {
          var button = '<button type="button" ng-click="' + $scope.showAlert + '()">click</button>';
          angular.element(document.body).append($compile(button)($scope));
    }
```

HTML: `<button type="button" ng-click="createExample()">test</button>`

When user clicks on button, createExample() method will be invoked. This method will create another button which will be having ng-click. This ng-clicks holds a method which give alert.

I'm getting error below:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 12 of the expression [function (){
       alert('pass'); 
    }()] starting at [{
       alert('pass'); 
    }()].
    at Error (native)
    at throwError (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:5830:11)
    at parser (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:5824:5)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:6387:29
    at https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:12493:18
    at nodeLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:4223:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:3838:14)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:3750:30
    at Object.$scope.createExample (http://fiddle.jshell.net/JKBbV/751/show/:44:65)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js:6129:19 <button type="button" ng-click="function (){
       alert('pass'); 
    }()" class="ng-scope">
```

$compile is the only option i have.
How to make this work??

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/751/)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click` takes the handler name to execute, here you are evaluating the method content.

Correct code would simply be :

```
    $scope.showAlert = function(){
       alert('pass'); 
    }
    $scope.createExample = function() {
          var button = '<button type="button" ng-click="showAlert()">click</button>';
          angular.element(document.body).append($compile(button)($scope));
    }
```